# How to code google-services.json file (download link broken)?

Tags: json, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

Although I have analytics account, signed in with chrome when attempting to download etc. the famous [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/) to download the generated file is broken.

So - How can I configure it by myself? This should be proper simple code task...:

Create new `.json` file in your project and what to put inside? Google's documentation assumes the link always works and I'm struggling to find instructions on how to code this file by myself.

Thanks,

Comment: I have just checked, the link is normal

Comment: @BNK No doubt the link is OK, but because from some reason it's not working in single case I thought it's might be good SW Q to know how to code such things alone - this is a kind of things we programmers like - to be independent from magic ui code generators and wrappers.... By the way - for me it's still broken link, strange.

Comment: I think if you have succesfully created that .json file from Google's site, then you can open it by Notepad or Notepad+ to view its content and find out how to create it manually :)

Comment: The problem I don't - for me it's still "magic file" generated by Force majeure. And knowing it's just a json and this is what sticking me to continue the workflow is...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server-side Google Analytics Experiments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900705/server-side-google-analytics-experiments)